# What is the difference between volatile and fluctuation in terms of stock?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, terminology

Differences between volatile and fluctuation? I am new to the stock market, currently learning about the terminology and i came across these words. From what i know, volatile is like the speed and range of a stock (ie movement) and i googled what fluctuation means and it defines fluctuation as 'an irregular rising and falling in number or amount'. So please clear thing up for me.

Answer (score 1):

Volatile is an adjective, fluctuation is a noun. :)

They are both referring to the same thing. The measure of how volatile a stock is is how much much it fluctuates from period to period. So a stock that fluctuates a lot has high *volatility*.

Answer (score 0):

[Volatility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(finance)?wprov=sfti1) is the more standard financial industry term. Fluctuation as far as I’m aware is more of a generic non industry synonym. But volatility isn’t quite as standardized a term as that Wikipedia article makes it appear. For example, there are other measures of volatility